# while loops with arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to have when the function is called that values in the array are displayed using while loops. It will display the first object except for the picture and not the other two

```
function products(){
    var txt=""
    var appliance = 0
var products = new Array();
products[0] = {name: "refrigerator" , price:88.99, 

    img:"img/refrigerator.jpg"};
products[1] = {name: "microwave oven" , price: 76.99 , img:"img/microwave.png"};
products[2] = {name: "dishwasher" , price:276.67 , img:"img/dishwasher.jpg"};
    /*var appliance = products[x].name + " " + products[x].price + " '" + products[x].img + "'>"*/
    while(appliance < 3){
        txt +=products[appliance].name + ' ' + products[appliance].price +" <img src='"+ products[appliance].img;"'>";
        appliance++;
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = txt
    }
    }
```

Comment: What are you intended to see? A certain property of the `products` object or the entire thing printed out?

Comment: The loop itself is fine (although it would be better to avoid the hard-coded values and the `for` form is often more idiomatic). Please write a title - and use tags - that apply to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
products[appliance].name + ' ' + products[appliance].price + products[appliance].img;
```

Otherwise you are trying to show an array.

Notice you forgot the `>` in :

```
<img src=img/refrigerator.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt += products[ appliance ].name + " " + products[ appliance ].price + " '" + products[ appliance ].img + "'>" +" <br />";
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function products(){
    var txt=""
    var appliance = 0
var products = new Array();
products[0] = {name: "refrigerator" , price:88.99, img:"img/refrigerator.jpg"};
products[1] = {name: "microwave oven" , price: 76.99 , img:"img/microwave.jpg"};
products[2] = {name: "dishwasher" , price:276.67 , img:"img/dishwasher.jpg"};

while(appliance < 3){
    txt +=products[appliance].name + ' ' + products[appliance].price +" <img src='"+ products[appliance].img + "'>" +" <br />";
    appliance++;
}
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = txt
}
}
```

solving my own code like a boss